# Passing JSON from Grails Controller to d3 - how to get the .gsp side working?

Tags: javascript, json, grails, d3.js

I want pass a map from a grails controller as JSON to d3, and use the d3.json() method to parse it

my controller looks like this

```
    def graph() {

      def map = [[source: "NodeOne", "target": "NodeTwo", "type": "type"],
        ["source": "NodeOne", "target": "NodeThree", "type": "type"]]

      render map as JSON
    }
```

the gsp script side looks like this: (d3 example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).
d3.json() renders a json at URL

```
 d3.json( URL , function(error, graph) {...[more code here]...}
```

what do I need to put in for URL to get my map rendered in d3? When I create a link to the controller, instead of loading the view, the JSON gets printed out as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested the below code :hope it helps
In your  XX.gsp

```
<script>
var url = "${createLink(controller:'yourControllerName',action: 'graph') }";
d3.json( url , function(error, graph) {...[more code here]...}
</script>
```